Cuda nvJitLink error because fatbin does not contains the correct function
Hi I am trying to compile my application with fatbin flag is active:
set_property(TARGET offline PROPERTY CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION ON)
The error code is:
error   : Undefined reference to '_Z7computefff' in 'ltoPtx'

error: nvJitLinkComplete(handle) failed with error 6
error: ERROR 9: finish

When I compiled the code directly using the next command the code run correctly:
nvcc -arch=lto_86 -rdc=true -fatbin offline.cu 
When I used Cmake to configure the build the build line is:
Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/offlineLib.dir/offline.fatbin
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler   -std=c++17 "--generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86]" -MD -MT CMakeFiles/offlineLib.dir/offline.fatbin -MF CMakeFiles/offlineLib.dir/offline.fatbin.d -x cu -fatbin /home/Yehonatans/tmp/jitEx/offline.cu -o CMakeFiles/offlineLib.dir/offline.fatbin

My cmake file is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(TestJitLto CUDA)


set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED cudadevrt cudart nvJitLink)


# Find the path to nvcc

message(STATUS "nvcc found at: ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER}")
add_executable(TestJitLto online.cu)

set_target_properties(TestJitLto PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)


target_link_libraries(TestJitLto PUBLIC CUDA::nvrtc CUDA::nvJitLink cuda  CUDA::cudart)

add_library(offlineLib OBJECT offline.cu )
set_property(TARGET offlineLib PROPERTY CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION ON)


Online code
#include <nvrtc.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <nvJitLink.h>
#include <nvrtc.h>
#include <iostream>

#define NUM_THREADS 128
#define NUM_BLOCKS 32

#define NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(x)                                        \
  do {                                                            \
    nvrtcResult result = x;                                       \
    if (result != NVRTC_SUCCESS) {                                \
      std::cerr << "\nerror: " #x " failed with error "           \
                << nvrtcGetErrorString(result) << '\n';           \
      exit(1);                                                    \
    }                                                             \
  } while(0)
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(x)                                         \
  do {                                                            \
    CUresult result = x;                                          \
    if (result != CUDA_SUCCESS) {                                 \
      const char *msg;                                            \
      cuGetErrorName(result, &msg);                               \
      std::cerr << "\nerror: " #x " failed with error "           \
                << msg << '\n';                                   \
      exit(1);                                                    \
    }                                                             \
  } while(0)
#define NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(h,x)                                  \
  do {                                                            \
    nvJitLinkResult result = x;                                   \
    if (result != NVJITLINK_SUCCESS) {                            \
      std::cerr << "\nerror: " #x " failed with error "           \
                << result << '\n';                                \
      size_t lsize;                                               \
      result = nvJitLinkGetErrorLogSize(h, &lsize);               \
      if (result == NVJITLINK_SUCCESS && lsize > 0) {             \
        char *log = (char*)malloc(lsize);                         \
    result = nvJitLinkGetErrorLog(h, log);                        \
    if (result == NVJITLINK_SUCCESS) {                            \
      std::cerr << "error: " << log << '\n';                      \
      free(log);                                                  \
    }                                                             \
      }                                                           \
      exit(1);                                                    \
    }                                                             \
  } while(0)

const char *lto_saxpy = "                                       \n\
extern __device__ float compute(float a, float x, float y);     \n\
                                                                \n\
extern \"C\" __global__                                         \n\
void saxpy(float a, float *x, float *y, float *out, size_t n)   \n\
{                                                               \n\
  size_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;           \n\
  if (tid < n) {                                                \n\
    out[tid] = compute(a, x[tid], y[tid]);                      \n\
  }                                                             \n\
}                                                               \n";



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  size_t numBlocks = 32;
  size_t numThreads = 128;
  // Create an instance of nvrtcProgram with the code string.
  nvrtcProgram prog;
  NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(
    nvrtcCreateProgram(&prog,                       // prog
                       lto_saxpy,                   // buffer
                       "lto_saxpy.cu",              // name
                       0,                           // numHeaders
                       NULL,                        // headers
                       NULL));                      // includeNames

  // specify that LTO IR should be generated for LTO operation
  const char *opts[] = {"-dlto",
                        "--relocatable-device-code=true"};
  nvrtcResult compileResult = nvrtcCompileProgram(prog,  // prog
                                                  2,     // numOptions
                                                  opts); // options
  // Obtain compilation log from the program.
  size_t logSize;
  NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(nvrtcGetProgramLogSize(prog, &logSize));
  char *log = new char[logSize];
  NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(nvrtcGetProgramLog(prog, log));
  std::cout << log << '\n';
  delete[] log;
  if (compileResult != NVRTC_SUCCESS) {
    exit(1);
  }
  // Obtain generated LTO IR from the program.
  size_t LTOIRSize;
  NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(nvrtcGetLTOIRSize(prog, &LTOIRSize));
  char *LTOIR = new char[LTOIRSize];
  NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(nvrtcGetLTOIR(prog, LTOIR));
  // Destroy the program.
  NVRTC_SAFE_CALL(nvrtcDestroyProgram(&prog));

  CUdevice cuDevice;
  CUcontext context;
  CUmodule module;
  CUfunction kernel;
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuInit(0));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuDeviceGet(&cuDevice, 0));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, cuDevice));

  // Load the generated LTO IR and the LTO IR generated offline
  // and link them together.
  nvJitLinkHandle handle;
  // Dynamically determine the arch to link for
  int major = 0;
  int minor = 0;
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuDeviceGetAttribute(&major,
                   CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MAJOR, cuDevice));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuDeviceGetAttribute(&minor,
                   CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MINOR, cuDevice));
  int arch = major*10 + minor;
  char smbuf[16];
  sprintf(smbuf, "-arch=sm_%d", arch);
  const char *lopts[] = {"-lto", smbuf};
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkCreate(&handle, 2, lopts));

  // NOTE: assumes "offline.fatbin" is in the current directory
  // The fatbinary contains LTO IR generated offline using nvcc
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkAddFile(handle, NVJITLINK_INPUT_FATBIN,
                                "offline.fatbin"));
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkAddData(handle, NVJITLINK_INPUT_LTOIR,
                            (void *)LTOIR, LTOIRSize, "lto_online"));

  // The call to nvJitLinkComplete causes linker to link together the two
  // LTO IR modules (offline and online), do optimization on the linked LTO IR,
  // and generate cubin from it.
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkComplete(handle));
  size_t cubinSize;
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkGetLinkedCubinSize(handle, &cubinSize));
  void *cubin = malloc(cubinSize);
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkGetLinkedCubin(handle, cubin));
  NVJITLINK_SAFE_CALL(handle, nvJitLinkDestroy(&handle));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuModuleLoadData(&module, cubin));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuModuleGetFunction(&kernel, module, "saxpy"));

  // Generate input for execution, and create output buffers.
  size_t n = NUM_THREADS * NUM_BLOCKS;
  size_t bufferSize = n * sizeof(float);
  float a = 5.1f;
  float *hX = new float[n], *hY = new float[n], *hOut = new float[n];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    hX[i] = static_cast<float>(i);
    hY[i] = static_cast<float>(i * 2);
  }
  CUdeviceptr dX, dY, dOut;
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemAlloc(&dX, bufferSize));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemAlloc(&dY, bufferSize));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemAlloc(&dOut, bufferSize));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemcpyHtoD(dX, hX, bufferSize));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemcpyHtoD(dY, hY, bufferSize));
  // Execute SAXPY.
  void *args[] = { &a, &dX, &dY, &dOut, &n };
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(
    cuLaunchKernel(kernel,
                   NUM_BLOCKS, 1, 1,    // grid dim
                   NUM_THREADS, 1, 1,   // block dim
                   0, NULL,             // shared mem and stream
                   args, 0));           // arguments
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuCtxSynchronize());
  // Retrieve and print output.
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemcpyDtoH(hOut, dOut, bufferSize));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << a << " * " << hX[i] << " + " << hY[i]
              << " = " << hOut[i] << '\n';
  }
  // Release resources.
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemFree(dX));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemFree(dY));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuMemFree(dOut));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuModuleUnload(module));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cuCtxDestroy(context));
  free(cubin);
  delete[] hX;
  delete[] hY;
  delete[] hOut;
  delete[] LTOIR;
  return 0;
}


offline code
__device__  float compute(float a, float x, float y) {
  return a * x + y;
}


What am I doing wrong and how can I overcome it?

Offline file needs to compiled with separable compilation (-rdc=true). Not doing so will result in the function being removed, as the compiler thinks it is unused. CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION can be used to enable separate compilation in CMake.
I tried using CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION with your example and it works:
$ tail -n3 CMakeLists.txt
set_target_properties(offlineLib PROPERTIES
    CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
    CUDA_FATBIN_COMPILATION ON)
$ (cd ./CMakeFiles/offlineLib.dir/ && compute-sanitizer ../../TestJitLto) | tail
5.1 * 4087 + 8174 = 29017.7
5.1 * 4088 + 8176 = 29024.8
5.1 * 4089 + 8178 = 29031.9
5.1 * 4090 + 8180 = 29039
5.1 * 4091 + 8182 = 29046.1
5.1 * 4092 + 8184 = 29053.2
5.1 * 4093 + 8186 = 29060.3
5.1 * 4094 + 8188 = 29067.4
5.1 * 4095 + 8190 = 29074.5
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

